# EAV in my cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on a new application and I have a need to use an EAV 
table style for a few different tables. Primarily the one I am posting 
about is my users table. I need to use EAV so that custom user defined 
fields can be added/displayed easily.

So far I have a simple table structure, I have a made an [ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK3Rv.png) for easy viewing.

The approach I am thinking about using is similar to this [post on key value pairs](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2010/07/27/keyvalue-tables-and-how-to-use-them-in-cakephp-1-3/). 
A simple beforeSave() that matches up fields to the form name.

There is only one issue with this that I am seeing, since I am not storing 
the field name(attribute_code from eav_attributes) with the value, how 
would I go about matching up the form field with the attribute_code 
and ultimately with the value the form field passed in?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get the problem. Do you mean that because you aren't storing the attribute key labels and the values in the same table, how do you go about matching them? The easiest solution would be to have a different model for eav_attributes and do a find('list') on it and then iterate over it to match attribute ID to attribute label.

Comment: You are correct, that is exactly what I am asking. The main reason for this post is to find the best practice for something like this. My original idea, was to using something similar to what is used in the blog augmented with what you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the approach in the blog is fine. Except instead of looping through the data array directly, you'd have to generate a list of the applicable EAV keys first since you're storing the keys separately. You just need to check that it exists in the data array before setting it so you don't set empty keys.

Basically you'd use three models rather than two, since you need to take in to account the model managing the attribute labels.